# How to use SVMhmm under MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, svm

Recently I am using SVMhmm package to handle classification problem. But I found that SVMhmm package is used under Linux or Windows (under Cygwin). I am thinking to use it under MATLAB of windows system. I know that there is an SVMstruct MATLAB interface package developed by Andrea Vedaldi. But can it handel HMM problem? Could someone help me with this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The web page (http://svmlight.joachims.org/svm_struct.html) for SVMhmm doesn't  mention a MATLAB interface. SVMstruct won't be able to do the job if you need the SVMhmm features. Just save your data from MATLAB as text file and the load it into SVMhmm. You contact the author (see web page for address) to ask about a MATLAB interface.